# Como criar um PDF a partir de dados de um Dicionário extraído de um arquivo .txt (Python)

Tags: python, pdf, dicionário

Eu tenho um `dict()` com dados de strings extraídas de um `arquivo.txt`.

```
dic = {}
dic[valor[0]] = valor[1]
print(dic)
>>> dic = {'Almir': 44, 'Ana': 36 ....}
```

Gostaria de salvar organizado em PDF da seguinte forma:

```
nome : 8585
nome : 83838
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim como sugerido pelo [@cryptotux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256601/3938), utilize a biblioteca [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/).

Para gerar o PDF através de um dicionário, onde cada palavra ficará em uma linha, faça:

```
import os
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

# Aqui vem o código de criação do dicionário `dic`

c = canvas.Canvas("arquivo.pdf")

# Move a origem do cursor para a parte superior esquerda
c.translate(inch,inch)

# Inicia um objeto texto limitando a área para que linhas 
# muito grandes, não ultrapassem a margem.
textobject = c.beginText(0, 650)
textobject.setFont("Helvetica-Oblique", 14)

# Percorrendo o dicionário definido anteriormente
for key, value in dic.items():
    textobject.textLine(key + ' : ' + value)

c.drawText(textobject)

c.showPage()
c.save()

os.system('arquivo.pdf')
```

Answer (score 3):

Instale o [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/):

```
pip install reportlab
```

Criando o PDF e salvando:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("arquivo.pdf")
#(x, y, string)
c.drawString(0,0,str(dic))
c.save()
```

Se quiser dar uma olhada na documentação: https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

Comment: cara, deu certo, mas qnd tento colocar com mais de uma linha os dados sao salvos todos numa unica linha

Comment: poderia me ajudar?

Comment: É realmente necessário usar PDF?Não é um formato nada prático de manipular via código.